# How to use bash to test directory limits of filesystem

Tags: bash, mkdir, limits

I need to test how many directories and files I can create on a filesystem (network mounted and local (usb) drives). I now use this bash line:

```
for i in {0..999999}; do mkdir -p $i; pushd $i; done
```

I know that it probably can be done better and I'd like to know how to. (in bash, not too complicated)

Comment: Not sure about `pushd`, but using the `cd` method, there is no limit (beyond the disk space).

Comment: In general using {START..END} with big ranges is a bad idea: bash expands them, so it will use a lot of RAM.

Comment: Doesn't matter, i have 8GB on this box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (true); do
  mkdir a
  cd a
done
```

Creates something like `./a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/`...

Comment: I don't really see how that's any better than the asker's solution other than using `cd` instead of `pushd`.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: No for-loop, but a while-loop. I think that it's a tiny bit cleaner.

Comment: Except now it can run forever, causing the hard drive to run out of inodes, babies to weep, and kittens to die.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: pushd has to remember all the directories it's been in. Therefore it'll run out of memory before hitting any disk limits.

Comment: The OP wants to find the limit, and the only way to do that is to hit the limit :-).

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: That's what the OP wants to do. :)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: As he just wants to fill a network drive with useless directories until it runs out of space, it should be ok... or something like that ;)

Answer (score 6):

Any file/directory is represented using an [inode](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-speakingunix14/index.html), take a look at `df -i` and you should get an overview of the number of files/directories you have the possiblity to create/use.

Answer (score 0):

The cd method actually works better and faster... My ext4 usb stick starts to mock at about 1040 folders...

And the network part is to test my wins2k3 config, but my virtualbox fails at the moment because I think I screwed something up...