# What's the max amount of files per directory? (Linux)

Tags: linux, filesystems, url-rewriting

I have to store a lot of image files, but I'm not sure about how to organize my directory structure.

Is there a limit of files per directory, or directories per directory?

Also, should I create the filenames randomly so they are not guessable? (so I don't get my bandwith hammered by someone trying to download all the files)

Comment: What filesystem? Each filesystem has different limits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279590/how-to-use-bash-to-test-directory-limits-of-filesystem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003885/200-000-images-in-single-folder-in-linux-perfomance-issue-or-not

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a nice overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Comment: that has one nice table of filesystem limits

Comment: The link provides some nice information about file system in general, but the above answer does not address all of the points in the question (e.g. filenaming). HappyDeveloper is really asking how to implement his image sever.